# Why the Ternary Operator isn't working right?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, ternary-operator

Well, I'm working in a Chat Room Website... and I have this Problem... For a reason the Ternary Operator doesn't give me the right output...

That's the Code Piece of code that does the Job...

```
html = html.replace(/(@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})/, "<span class='" + (myUsername == "$1".replace('@', '') ? "highlighted-username" : "") + "'>$1</span>");
```

Let's say That my name is "jimisdam" and someone writes in the Chat "@jimisdam"... So... I'm getting the $1 and removing the '@' to compare it with the myUsername(which is "jimisdam")

WHAT'S WRONG ??

Comment: Here's a nice way of doing this http://jsbin.com/fepugaxopa/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3):

JS doesn't know that you want it to substitute $1 into place before doing the replacement. It sees a method call to `html.replace` which takes 2 arguments:

- the regex to match
- the string to replace with

To calculate the second parameter, it evaluates this expression:

```
"<span class='" + (myUsername == "$1".replace('@', '') ? "highlighted-username" : "") + "'>$1</span>"
```

Note that `$1` doesn't mean anything special here, because we're still deciding what string to pass into the replacement function. So:

- `"$1".replace('@', '')` just results in `"$1"`
- so unless your username happens to be $1, the comparison will always be false
- so an empty string will be added to the class attribute
- so the argument passed will always be `"<span class=''>$1</span>"`

Only now does `replace` get to see the remaining instance of $1 and substitute in the captured value.

One way to achieve what you're trying to do is to [pass in a function rather than a string as the second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). That way, you get the matched sections of string as variables, and can use them to calculate the  replacement.

Untested example, because I'm on a phone:

```
html = html.replace(/(@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})/, function(match) { return "<span class='" + (myUsername == match.replace('@', '') ? "highlighted-username" : "") + "'>" + match + "</span>"; })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your “$1” string literal does not hold a submatch. That’s wrong.

However, the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method also takes a function as second argument. Try this:

```
html = html.replace(/(@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})/,function(){
    return '<span class="' +
           (myUsername == arguments[0].replace('@','') ? 'highlighted-username' : '')
           + '">' + arguments[0] + '</span>';
});
```